# how to query in view ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i have this in the controller

@ads = Ad.all(:joins => 'LEFT JOIN `states` ON ads.state_id = states.id')

but i have problem to query field of states table.
any idea?

```
<% @ads.each do |ad| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= ad.title %></td> <- title is ad field.no problem
    <td><%= ad.name %></td> <- name is states field.problem at here
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting with ad.name?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will work unless you have associations set up.  Unless performance is a concern, you may just want to use the association without joins

**ad.rb**

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
end
```

**state.rb**

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ads
end
```

**controller**

```
@ads = Ad.all
```

**view**

```
  <% @ads.each do |ad| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= ad.title %></td>
        <td>
            <%= ad.state.name %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: you can also look at includes if performance is a concern.. might fit your need better than joins

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put this: `ads.state_id = states.id` like this: `#{ads.state_id = states.id}`

The `#{ }` will evaluate the ruby code inside. Otherwise what you have is just text inside a string.

I'm not quite sure what your issue is, though, so I'm not totally sure that will fix it.

Comment: the joins should contain text in this particular query